# Bing Search Suggestions using Jquery

Tags: jquery, bing-api

I have  a requirement in my website where the user can type in some "text" in a textbox and i have to show some search suggestions in a drop down.  I have signed up for a Bing Search account and i got an account key. But i am not able to see any example code how to implement this feature using Jquery.

My website is written in Asp.Net MVC and it would be great if some one could point to an example code.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://api.bing.net/xml.aspx?Appid=<AppID>&sources=spell&query=cofee
```

Source: http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html

All you need to do is to post the REST API request via XHR (POST) and get the data as text. You can parse the repsonse with JSON.parse().

Comment: Am i suppose to use my accountkey as the APPId ? Thanks !

Comment: When i do this I am seeing "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below"  in the browser, Thanks !

Comment: Simply change the XML parameter to JSON to get a JSON response ;) `http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx....`

Comment: And yes: Use your API key. The entire process is explained in the link I posted in my answer under "Getting an AppID".

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an easy library to do this for my own needs back in June: [jquery-bingsearch](https://github.com/cbenard/jquery-bingsearch) (GitHub source and web page). I realize you probably already solved your issue but I wanted to leave this here for future Google juice.

I'm using it on my [personal web page](http://chrisbenard.net/search/).

### Usage

#### App Key

Get an app key by following step 1 on [this page](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/07/bing-search-api-azure-csharp.html).

#### HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bingsearch-min.js"></script>
```

#### Javascript

**Note:** At least one of `beforeSearchResults`, `afterSearchResults`, or `searchResultInterator`
must be passed in, or the plugin will do nothing (since there's nothing to which it can return
the results. This is in addition to the required fields listed below.

```
$.bingSearch({
    // Required: query text
    query: 'query text here',
    // Required (unless you use urlBase) by Bing Search API
    appKey: 'Put your Windows Azure Marketplace Bing Search API Primary Account Key here'
    // Optional (defaults to the Bing Search API Web Results Query).
    // Additional information: This feature allows you to proxy through a server-side
    //                         script in order to hide your API key, which is exposed to the
    //                         world if you set it client-side in appKey. An example PHP
    //                         script is included (searchproxy.php).
    urlBase: 'searchproxy.php',
    // Optional (defaults to 1): Page Number
    pageNumber: parseInt($('#pageNumber').val()),
    // Optional (defaults to 10): Page Size
    pageSize: 10,
    // Optional (defaults to null): Limit to site. Shortcut to adding "site:example.org " to query
    limitToSite: 'example.org',
    // Optional (defaults to false): Print console logging information about search results
    debug: false,
    // Optional: Function is called after search results are retrieved, but before the interator is called
    beforeSearchResults: function(data) {
        // Use data.hasMore, data.resultBatchCount
    },
    // Optional: Function is called once per result in the current batch
    searchResultIterator: function(data) {
        // Use data.ID, data.Title, data.Description, data.Url, data.DisplayUrl, data.Metadata.Type (check for undefined)
    },
    // Optional: Function is called after search results are retrieved and after all instances of the interator are called
    afterSearchResults: function(data) {
        // Use data.hasMore, data.resultBatchCount
    },
    // Optional: Called when there is an error retrieving results
    fail: function(data) {
        // data contains an error message
    }
});
```

Comment: Why the searchproxy.php? :) Javascript can do base 64 encoding with a plugin.

Comment: @giorgio79 It doesn't have anything to do with base64. The javascript does do the auth header on [lines 70 and 81](https://github.com/cbenard/jquery-bingsearch/blob/master/jquery.bingsearch.js#L70). The search proxy exists to hide the API keys from the end user viewing source by proxying it through server-side code. The plugin works with and without this. Example of client-side-only [here](http://cbenard.github.io/jquery-bingsearch/). Documentation [here](https://github.com/cbenard/jquery-bingsearch).